# Assigning values to a subset of a data frame with a dynamically generated name

Tags: r, dynamic, subset

```
for (BSyears in namelist) {                                      
    firstcol <- eval(as.name(BSyears))[,1]                        
    firstcol <- as.character(firstcol)
    EmptyRows <- sum(is.na(firstcol))                                       
    firstcol[is.na(firstcol)] <- paste("EMPTY_", 1:EmptyRows, sep = "")
    firstcol -> as.symbol(paste(BSyears,'[,1]', sep = ""))
}
```

My goal with this code is to take a series of scraped data frames stored as dataframes, and fill in all empty entries in the first column with a phrase `EMPTY_number`.

`namelist` is a vector of names of dynamically generated data frames.

The loop is meant to read the first column of all the data frames whose names are stored in `namelist`, coerce it into a `character` vector, find all the `NA` entries, and then replace all the NA entries in order with dynamically generated strings `EMPTY_1`, `EMPTY_2`, `EMPTY_3`, etc.

Everything here seems to work, except for this last line:

```
as.symbol(paste(BSyears,'[,1]', sep = "")) <- firstcol
```

That line was meant to reference the first column of the data frame given by the loop counter `BSyears`, and replace it with a new column.

RStudio always throws this error when I try to run that line:

```
Error in as.symbol(paste(BSyears, "[,1]", sep = "")) <- firstcol : 
  could not find function "as.symbol<-"
```

How can I fix this, or rewrite this to make it work as intended? I believe I may be breaking an obscure syntax rule with the way its currently written.

Here's a minimal example with one input:

```
> head(namelist)
[1] "BS2002" "BS2003" "BS2004" "BS2005" "BS2006" "BS2007"

> head(BS2002)
                                X1                    X2           X3
1 10-K for period ended 2002-12-31                  <NA>         <NA>
2                             <NA>          Dec. 31 2002 Dec. 31 2001
3                             <NA> (millions of dollars)         <NA>
4                           Assets                  <NA>         <NA>
5                   Current assets                  <NA>         <NA>
6        Cash and cash equivalents                  7229         6547
```

If `BSyears` is `BS2002`, the intended final output is:

```
                                X1                    X2           X3
1 10-K for period ended 2002-12-31                  <NA>         <NA>
2                          EMPTY_1          Dec. 31 2002 Dec. 31 2001
3                          EMPTY_2 (millions of dollars)         <NA>
4                           Assets                  <NA>         <NA>
5                   Current assets                  <NA>         <NA>
6        Cash and cash equivalents                  7229         6547
```

The motivation was to use `full_join` from `dplyr` to join all the balance sheets listed in `namelist` to create a single balance sheet spanning multiple years. `full_join` exhibits strange behaviors if `by = X1` contains any NA entries.

This script is meant to fill in to NA entries so that after joining the individual sheets, I can clean up all the "junk" rows in a single swoop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please take the time to construct a [mcve], including example input and expected output, and update your post accordingly.  It'll be a lot easier to help you that way.

Comment: Why make life hard and use `eval` and `as.symbol` and `assign` when you could just put the data frames in a `list`?

Comment: Ah. What a rookie mistake I made here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have already figured this out, but since I'll go ahead and post since I've got the code written...

```
# convert the data frames to a list
library(purrr)
df_list <-map(namelist, ~ get(.x))


# function for the replacement
replace_nas <- function(df, col_no) {
  x <- df[col_no]

  x[is.na(x)] <- paste0("EMPTY_", 1:sum(is.na(x)))
  df[col_no] <- x
  df
}

tmp2 <- df_list %>% map(~ replace_nas(.x, col_no = 1))
```